# making a thread within a class and having it execute on a funtion within the class in c++ (cpp)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to make a program where there are multiple threads, the only interaction between the threads should be a few variables created only for transfer between the threads. One of these will be a queue. I want to have one thread constantly writing to a file and I want the other threads to keep giving it lines to write.

But for simplicity reasons, I want to make this all happen from creating the class then simply calling a function called give_line() from that class. I want that thread that is writing to the file private so that other people cant be messing around with it.

```
class bar
{
private:
    std::queue<std::string> lines;    // The queue
    void write()                      // The function we call from thread
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world from other thread";
    }
public:
    bar()                             // constructor
    {
        std::thread writer(&bar::write, this);     // thread
    }
}

int main()
{
    bar testing;
    std::cout << "Hello World from main thread" << std::endl;

    /*
    What this does is it allows me to keep the console open till we get a enter key.
    */

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    std::cin.get();


    return 0;
}
```

.

```
output:
    Hello world from other thread
```

Why this makes no sense and why it doesn't work beats me. It starts up then bam it crashes. I can't figure this out. It works when I don't have it within a class, but then that someone else can mess with the thread and I really don't want that. I'm not going to be giving out too much code from the project unless I need to. The reason I'm creating this class and the other functions and variables are things you don't need to know.

I understand that I need a writer.join() somewhere. But that's for later. I want to have another variable be able to end everything at once. That variable can only be accessed from the main thread, so the other threads cant mess with it. kindof like a kill_all variable.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Ah yes, you're right. It kills your program, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here, but, first and foremost is that `std::thread`'s constructor takes a function to execute in a newly started thread. Looks like you are not passing a function, you are passing a class method.

I'm fairly certain that your compiler was yelling at you, when it tried to compile this code. Just because your compiler chose to produce some kind of a compiled object file, despite the errors it reported, doesn't mean that the compiler diagnostic can be ignored.

You were probably trying to do something like this:

```
static void invoke_write(bar *p)
{
     p->write();
}

bar()
{
     std::thread writer(&invoke_write, this); 
}
```

Now, you're invoking a static function, and passing it a pointer to the instantiating class, which it uses to invoke the class method.

But the real reason you're crashing is because you're instantiating an instance of `std::thread` inside the scope of `bar`'s constructor.

And when `bar`'s constructor returns, the `std::thread` object, just like any other function/method-scoped object, gets destroyed, invoking its destructor. But, you just started the thread, which is running, and if a `std::thread`'s destructor gets invoked while the thread is still running, `terminate()` gets invoked, aborting the program.

You must `join()` before destroying an instance of `std::thread`, if the thread is running. So, either something like this:

```
bar()
{
     std::thread writer(&invoke_write, this); 

     writer.join();
}
```

Or, make an instance of `std::thread` a class member, instantiating it in the constructor, and joining to it in the destructor. Something like:

```
    bar() : writer(&invoke_write, this)
    {
    }

    ~bar()
    {
         writer.join();
    }

private:

    std::thread writer;
```

Of course, which approach is the correct one depends on your application's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A simple change to your class, with a nod to @Sam Varchavchik, is to ensure that you don't lose the thread objects immediately after you create it.

```
class bar
{
private:
    std::queue<std::string> lines;    // The queue
    std::thread writer;

    void write()                      // The function we call from thread
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world from other thread";
    }
public:
    bar() : writer{&bar::write, this} {}

    ~bar()
    {
        writer.join();
    }
};
```

Here, the writer thread is initialized in the constructor, and we wait for it to finish in the destructor.

You can watch the slightly altered code run here:  http://ideone.com/Xf4dw5

As Sam mentioned, you couldn't in older C++ just pass in a class method to create a thread, because it needs to have the object as well.  Modern c++ lets this work, by binding the two together, as you have done by passing 'this' into the thread constructor.